# Integrate Report Builder in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, reportbuilder

I have an ASP.NET Core project and now I want to get reports from that.
I want to create a report by query (like reports in report builder) with a parameter. I want to pass this parameter from C# and then show the data in PDF.

I tried report builder poco way but I had to give the data to report by code but I want to get data from query.

Is it possible?

Comment: Most databases support poco class mapping to databases, could you be more clear about the question?